# Test Drag and drop with jest (dnd-kit)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, drag-and-drop, react-testing-library, dnd-kit

I'm trying to test drag and drop with dnd-kit (testing-library / jest) and I can't,

I tested to trigger the listeners events of the useDraggable hook,

```
it.only("should pass the pack in the activatedPack zone by drag and drop", async () => {
            const ui = (
                <AppWrapper
                    routeParams={{
                        id: "602fdec72b21c534fc8ca136",
                    }}
                    useQueryResponses={{
                        "user|602fdec72b21c534fc8ca136|availablePacks": {
                            data: mockDataAvailable,
                            isSuccess: true,
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    <Packs />
                </AppWrapper>
            );

            const { queryByTestId } = render(ui);

            const draggableItem = queryByTestId(
                "draggableItem_6137129fb0337106e08680fd"
            );

            const dropZone = queryByTestId("activatedPacks");

            fireEvent.dragStart(draggableItem);
            fireEvent.drop(dropZone);
        });
```

Thank you for your support ;)

Comment: Any logs or errors? What's the current behavior and why it's not sufficient?